# What are the best practices to configure CloudWatch alarms for a Tomcat webapp?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, tomcat8

I have a Tomcat webapp deployed on Elastic Beanstalk for which I want to configure CloudWatch alarms, especially for when the web server is down. The Tomcat container uses Google OAuth2 for authentication and a custom MongoDB Realm for authorization. So there are no public URLs to hit as any request would be redirected to Google for authentication.

From the research that I've done, it looks like an alarm for [CPU Utilization's insufficient data](https://serverfault.com/a/341442/418905) is the answer to getting notified if the web-server is down. However, I've read [conflicting comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48964003/3906773) that CPU Utilization has nothing to do with a server being down and an Elastic Load Balancer health check should be used instead.

Other solutions require you to install [custom CloudWatch libraries](http://johnhunsley.blogspot.com/2016/03/custom-cloudwatch-tomcat-jvm-metrics.html) or using [external tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13286690/3906773).

So what are the best practices for such monitoring, preferably using tools provided by AWS?